# How to implement a trait for a generic struct where the generic struct's type parameters don't appear in the trait signature

Tags: rust

I want a custom `fmt` for a wrapper struct (`PrettyRange<T>`) containing a [`RangeBounds<V>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.RangeBounds.html), which is a generic trait. I want `T: RangeBounds<V>` and `V: std::fmt::Display`, but I can't figure out how to make the compiler happy because `V` doesn't appear directly in `PrettyRange<T>`'s type signature.

```rust
pub struct PrettyRange<T> {
    inner: T
}

impl<V, T> std::fmt::Display for PrettyRange<T> 
where 
    T: std::ops::RangeBounds<V>,
    V: std::fmt::Display,
{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result  {
        //  use methods from RangeBounds here to make a pretty string
    }
}
```

The relevant error:

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `V` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
 --> src/lib.rs:5:6
  |
5 | impl<V, T> std::fmt::Display for PrettyRange<T> 
  |      ^ unconstrained type parameter

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0207`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

I've tried various combinations of constraining the `impl`, constraining the `fn fmt` with no success.

Comment: You can't. It must appear on the struct or the trait. But this may be a XY problem.

Comment: Suppose there is a type that implements both `RangeBounds<usize>` and `RangeBounds<isize>`. What will be `V`'s type?

Comment: This is not theoretical: for instance, `Range<&T>` impls both `RangeBounds<T>` and `RangeBounds<&T>`.